# Search data in Observable

Tags: mongodb, angular

I'd like to have a search input, that display the result on keypress.
At the moment, this is what I have :

```
mylist: Observable<MyData[]>;
term = new FormControl();
    ngOnInit() {
        this.mylist = this.term.valueChanges
                    .debounceTime(400)
                    .distinctUntilChanged()
                    .switchMap(term => this.searchData(term));
    }

    searchData(valueToSearch:string){
        if(valueToSearch == ''){
            this.channels = MyData.find();
        }
        return MyData.find({'title':new RegExp(valueToSearch)});
    }
```

It works quite well, but I have trouble to initialize "mylist", and I think my method isn't performant at all.

Basically, I want when my component is initialize, that:

```
this.mylist = MyData.find();
```

And on keypress, I want my search to be done on this.mylist, to avoid doing too much request.
Is it possible ?
I hope I'm clear.

Thanks by advance guys.

Comment: `MyData` object refers to?

Comment: It refers to a collection I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must `subscribe` to the mapped data. Modify to the below code

```
this.term.valueChanges
    .debounceTime(400)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .switchMap(term => this.searchData(term))
    .subscribe((result) => {
            this.mylist = result
        });;
```

@Julia is correct , modify your `searchData()` function as below

```
searchData(valueToSearch:string):Observable<any> {
        if(valueToSearch == ''){
            this.channels = MyData.find();
        }
        return <Observable<any>>MyData.find({'title':new RegExp(valueToSearch)});
    }
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but I got this error:
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Observable<MyData[]>'.

Comment: where do you get this error? which line? are you available in team viewer?

Comment: looks like searchData does not return an observable but a value

Comment: I know it's been a long time, but it works perfectly ! Thanks :)